# Rails: unique validation fails when updating?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I am searching or initializing and object and then updating it:

```
  booking = Booking.where(deal_id: params["id"]).first_or_initialize
  if booking.update!(
    names: "some names",
    deal_id: params["id"]
    )
  some other stuff
```

is failing with the message

```
Validation failed: deal_id has already been taken
```

If I am calling first or initialize and then update, how is this error possible? What needs to be fixed? Is it because I am adding deal_id again on the update line?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try removing `deal_id: params["id"]` from the `update!` params and see if that works? `first_or_initialize` should already set that value and that could be the source of the problem.

Comment: i did! the error seems to be gone :)